# Skip Ivy resolve and download dependencies manually instead

Tags: ant, cassandra, ivy

I am trying to install cassandra, and am having difficulty in resolving certain dependencies. Is there any way to simply download the jar files directly and skip the ivy resolve option.

I am not familiar with Apache Ant or with Apache Ivy.

The Apache Ivy settings are described here: https://gist.github.com/nipunarora/5fa2c22770f575d81a0698644c5eeb02

The Apache Ivy is here:
https://gist.github.com/nipunarora/d24f15768ff13470c5eb55a4f356650a

A couple of the dependencies from cloudera cannot be resolved. I can download the jar files from the web, so I would like to skip resolving dependencies and downloading them manually instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually managing dependencies is not fun... I wouldn't recommend it....

Your issue appears to be that cloudera have changed their repository URL. I discovered a second issue where the hadoop streaming artifact was missing. I pulled the jar from the hadoop project instead.

### Ivy settings file

I suggest using an alternative and simpler settings:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" />
    <ibiblio name="cloudera" root="https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/repo" m2compatible="true" />
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation="com.cloudera.hadoop" resolver="cloudera" />
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Basically configure ivy to download cloudera artifacts from the cloudera repo and everything else from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/)

### Missing hadoop streaming artifact

A search of the cloudera repository was unable to find your desired dependency:

- [dependency org="com.cloudera.hadoop" name="hadoop-streaming" rev="0.20.2-320"](https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/search/package/eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJzZWFyY2giOiJnYXZjIiwiZ3JvdXBJRCI6ImNvbS5jbG91ZGVyYS5oYWRvb3AiLCJhcnRpZmFjdElEIjoiaGFkb29wLXN0cmVhbWluZyIsInNlbGVjdGVkUmVwb3NpdG9yaWVzIjpbXX0sInNlbGVjdGVkUGFja2FnZVR5cGUiOnsiaWQiOiJnYXZjIiwiZGlzcGxheU5hbWUiOiJHQVZDIiwiaWNvbiI6InBvbSJ9LCJzZWxlY3RlZFJlcG9zaXRvcmllcyI6W10sImNvbHVtbnMiOlsiYXJ0aWZhY3QiLCJncm91cElEIiwiYXJ0aWZhY3RJRCIsInZlcnNpb24iLCJjbGFzc2lmaWVyIiwicmVwbyIsInBhdGgiLCJtb2RpZmllZCJdfQ==)

I suggest the following ivy file:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="apache-cassandra" module="cassandra"/>

  <configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
  </configurations>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- FIXME: paranamer can be dropped after we're depending on avro                                                        
    (since it depends on them). -->
    <dependency org="com.thoughtworks.paranamer" name="paranamer-ant" rev="2.1" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.6"  conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1.1" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.rat" name="apache-rat" rev="0.6"  conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="net.sf.jopt-simple" name="jopt-simple" rev="3.2" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="net.java.dev.jna" name="jna" rev="3.2.7" conf="compile->default"/>

    <dependency org="com.cloudera.hadoop" name="hadoop-core" rev="0.20.2-320" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.hadoop" name="hadoop-streaming" rev="2.7.2" conf="compile->default"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Note:

- I have included a configuration mappings to give more control over dependencies (Good ivy habit, similar to how scopes work in Maven).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. this helped me a lot ... hardly had to figure out anything myself :)